# Some Confusion in IF Condition of PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

This is the code

```
$a = 'Rs 15.25';
if ( $a != '' && $a! = 0 ) {
    echo "Inside If";
} else {
    echo "Outside If";
}
```

actually I want to Print "Inside If" so that's why I put $a='Some String Value'. But it always prints "Outside If". Then I changed my code to

```
$a = 'Rs 15.25';
if ( $a != '' && $a != '0' ) {
    echo "Inside If";
} else {
    echo "Outside If";
}
```

I have just added single quotes to 0. Then i got the exact output as i want. But I didn't understand why this happens.
So please help me with this.

Comment: [Loose type comparisons](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) again

Comment: @MarkBaker and also simple search for millions of such questions. Sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does weak type comparison, that is, it converts both operands to the same type before doing the actual comparison.

If one of the operands is a number, the other one is converted to a number as well. If the second operand is a string and contains no digits, it is silently converted to the number `0`.

To avoid this whole issue, use string type checking with the operator `!==` (`===` for equality).

```
if($a !== '' && $a !== 0) {
    echo "Inside If";
} else {
    echo "Outside If";
}
```

Comment: thanx Knittl, it works  and also i come to know why this is happening.

Comment: Yep, the main point is that any string *not starting* with a digit will be silently converted to an integer *0*.

Comment: @Havelock : yep..got it :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all you when you have multiple conditions on an if statement you should always enclose  each of them within brackets

So first thing you should do is to change your code to

```
     $a='Rs 15.25';
    if(($a!='') && ($a!='0'))
    {
         echo "Inside If";
    }else
    {
         echo "Outside If";
    }
```

Comment: How does this answer his question?

Comment: I know that for the compiler id doesn't make much difference but people sometimes have problems debugging their code cos they do not clearly separate the conditions that should be evaluated, and I believe that when you are debugging you should always address the obvious things first.  But you guys can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I would say if there were one more condition with `||` enclosed with separate braces, you will have a bad time

Comment: And actually I just tested the code I suggested and it generates the the output desired by the OP, so I can't understand why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I would imagine that your answer was downvoted for not answering the question (which was "I don't understand the difference between comparing with `0` and `'0'`").

Comment: Ok, Thanks Steven, i guess i did not read the end of the question properly.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP 0 = FALSE, 1 = TRUE.
if($a != 0) -> if($a != FALSE)
if $a = 'Rs 15.25',  $a != false and $a not empty, then you have echo "Outside If";

Comment: The fulfillment of both conditions should mean that the output is "inside". Clearly, $a == 0.